# Maximal time interval for IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i find the  maximal time interval $J$ for which the Theorem of Existence and Uniqueness guarantees the existence and uniqueness of a solution $y : J → R$
for the IVP
$$
  y'=(y^2)+(1/t)  ,~~  y(1)=1
$$

Comment: What do you know about this equation, what have you tried?

Comment: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The following is an exploration of what is close to the maximally achievable. The interval approximation at the end is not an exact proof. Per the wording of the task that you reproduced, you are probably expected to find a much smaller interval, a box $(t,y)\in[1-a,1+a]\times[1-b,1+b]$ where the direct Picard iteration is contracting in the unmodified supremum norm.

---

The ODE is a Riccati equation. Use the parametrization $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ to get the equivalent second order linear DE
$$
tu''+u=0,~~ u(1)=-1,~u'(1)=1.
$$
This has a solution on $(0,\infty)$. The domain of $y$ is bounded by zero and the roots of $u$ closest to $t=1$ on both sides.

From WKB theory one gets the second order approximation around $t=0$ 
$$
u(t) = t^{1/4}(-\cos(2(\sqrt{t}-1))+B\sin(2(\sqrt{t}-1))),
\\
u'(1) = -\frac14 + B\implies B=\frac54.
$$
Assuming this approximation is still good at $t=1$ and a little to its right, the limiting roots are at $2(\sqrt{t}-1)=\arctan\frac45+k\pi\iff t=(1+\tfrac12\arctan\frac45+k\frac\pi2)^2$, $k\in\Bbb Z$. This gives with $k=-1,0$ the interval $J=(0.054488, 1.78855)$ as an interval where the solution should exist.

The plot of the numerical solution for $u$ confirms the upper bound and shows that there is no root at the lower bound, that is, the interval starts at $t=0$.

[image: plot of parametrization]
[image: plot of solution]

The vertical line is the position of the pole, it is outside the domain of the solution.